# Arp poisoning is disrupting the LAN

Tags: penetration-test, man-in-the-middle, arp-spoofing, arp

I'm poisoning my home network, I was able to do it 1 time. When i tried several more times to poison the wifi network or the cable network the "target" started to  lose connectivity in both cases.
Kernel forwarding is enabled, tried with promisc. mode, the problem is not in the slow processing  (CPU load is 20-30%), The Gratutious ARP packets are being broadcasted all the time with the spoofed address.
I tried poisoning only the client and poisoning both directions with `arpspoof` and `ettercap` - same result. I have experience in  networking and Linux but not so experienced with pen testing so maybe I'm missing something.
I'm using low-end tp-link 940 router

Comment: What do you mean "started" to lose connectivity? Have you used Wireshark on your attacking machine to see what's happening? Also, welcome to Information Security Stack Exchange!

Comment: Yes, The DNS query/replay is working, but the TCP traffic is problematic i see a lot of retransmission, so the 'victim' can not connect to anything

Comment: Hm, we'd probably need more technical detail/output. This type of question may be more appropriate for a forum/discussion format rather than Q&A since there may be a bit of back and forth for troubleshooting.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  There is a lot of unknown like how devices respond to GARP. and other  specific details. I  will continue the debuging and if I find a solution I  will post it.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out. The problem was Network Manager, after I have stopped it and ran `arpspoof` everything worked like a charm. The traffic was flowing without any problem.